# Bold text through C++ write statement

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, formatting, command-line-interface

I'm working on a dictionary server via telnet, and I'd like it to return it in this format:

```
  **word** (wordType): wordDef wordDef wordDef wordDef
wordDef wordDef wordDef.
```

Right now I'm outputting the code using:

```
write( my_socket, ("%s", word.data()    ), word.length()    ); // Bold this
write( my_socket, ("%s", theRest.data() ), theRest.length() );
```

So I'd like that first line to be bolded.

## Edit

Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is for a command line.

Comment: I'm afraid the style of a Font cannot be sent thru a socket. Why don't use HTML syntax like this "<b>This text is bold</b>", and the receiver checks for those labels and acts accordingly.

Comment: Hmm. It won't bold the text within a code snippet. Should I post that on Meta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using using something like [VT100 escape sequences](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlvt100.html). Since your server is telnet based the user is likely to have a client that supports various terminal modes.

For instance if you wanted to turn on bold for a VT100 terminal you would output

```
ESC[1m
```

where "ESC" is the character value 0x1b. To switch back to normal formatting output

```
ESC[0m
```

To use this in your application you can change the example lines from your question to the following.

```
std::string str = "Hello!"
write( my_socket, "\x1b[1m", 4); // Turn on bold formatting
write( my_socket, str.c_str(), str.size()); // output string
write( my_socket, "\x1b[0m", 4); // Turn all formatting off
```

There other terminal modes such as VT52, VT220, etc. You might want to look into using [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) although it might be a bit heavy if all you need is simple bold on/off.

Comment: And how exactly should that be put in? `string bold("ESC[1m");`?

Comment: @JShoe The size is the number of characters in the escape sequence which in this case is 4 bytes. I have updated my answer with some example code. I recommend storing the escape sequences in `std::string` although I use C style strings for brevity in the example.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. I actually got so tired of trying to `write` c++ strings, I made my own wrapper, here: https://gist.github.com/JoePShoulak/5592599

Comment: Since the function does not need to modify `word` change it to `int Send(int socket, const string& word)`. This will prevent modifying `word` and will allow you to pass rvalues to `Send`

Comment: Does that mean that I then have to pass a pointer instead of a string?

Comment: Currently you are passing strings to `Send` by value. This means that a copy of the string is created before `Send` is called. Passing by const reference eliminates the copy and allows you to pass rvalues. You can do either `std::string str; Send(sock, str);' or `Send(sock, "hello");` just like before since `std::string` has an implicit conversion constructor for C style strings.